# How to not make window.location relative to file

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

I don't know why I couldn't find a reason why this was happening or how to fix it, but here is my code:

```js
window.location.href=("www.google.com");
```

I want this code to make the page go to google.com, but instead it adds the path of my javascript file to the URL:

file:///home/chronos/u-d39822a3dd3bcc85fb11b442cbd253ea0275a8af/Downloads/**www.google.com**

How do I make it so that it simply goes to google.com? And is there an entirely different way I should be doing this?

Comment: You need to start with a protocol (`http://`) for an entirely absolute URL, or a `/` for a domain-relative URL. On its own, `www.google.com` is only valid as an entirely-relative URL.

Comment: Ooooh, I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `http://` protocol, otherwise it will try to start the path relative to your page url.  You also can just use window.location

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Answer (score 2):

Without specifying protocol, it's like a relative link base on your current URL.

Very similar to this case:

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML += anchors[i].href+'<br>';
}
```

```html
<p><a href="asdf.com">haha</a></p>
<p><a href="http://qwer.com">hoho</a></p>
<p><div></div></p>
```